# Parse positions of dictionary values into a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Let's say you have a dictionary with the following type of data:

```
{'abc':'AGCTAC', 'def': 'AGGTAC', 'ghi':'AGGTAG'}
```

I want to be able to run a function that shows the values at each position, e.g.

```
(('A','A','A'),('G','G','G'),('C','G','G'))
```

And then be able to run a counter such as people have suggested with collections Counter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> d = {'abc':'AGCTAC', 'def': 'AGGTAC', 'ghi':'AGGTAG'}
>>> zip(*d.values())
[('A', 'A', 'A'), ('G', 'G', 'G'), ('C', 'G', 'G'), ('T', 'T', 'T'), ('A', 'A', 'A'), ('C', 'G', 'C')]
```

Remember that dicts are unordered, so the elements in the tuples may occur in a different order. However the order will be the same for all the tuples

In Python3, zip returns a "zip object" so you need to wrap `tuple()` around it

```
>>> tuple(zip(*d.values()))
(('A', 'A', 'A'), ('G', 'G', 'G'), ('C', 'G', 'G'), ('T', 'T', 'T'), ('A', 'A', 'A'), ('C', 'G', 'C'))
```

If you don't need the intermediate tuple, just pass to `Counter`

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(zip(*d.values()))
Counter({('A', 'A', 'A'): 2, ('C', 'G', 'G'): 1, ('G', 'G', 'G'): 1, ('T', 'T', 'T'): 1, ('C', 'G', 'C'): 1})
```

Comment: If insertion order is important, there is also `collections.OrderedDict`.

Comment: … and of course `Counter.most_common(…)` will return the counts in sorted order of most to least frequent n-tuples